# Circuit that outputs signal A when AC sine is positive and signal B when AC sine is negative

Tags: ac, zero-crossing

I need help designing a circuit that outputs Signal A high when AC sine wave is positive and Signal B high when the sine wave is negative. It's part of a larger project that cycles power in a transformer.

I have the below circuit working but it's not accurate enough.  Signal A and B don't start/stop exactly at the zero-cross of the input sine wave. Any help appreciated!

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an XY question. What are you trying to do with this signal and "cycling power in a transformer"?

Comment: Have you considered an OPAmp?

Comment: Is a 4N25 Opto an OPAmp?  (I'm new to electronics)

Comment: bridge rectifier?

Comment: The two signals each start a timer that is controlling other switches downstream that switch power on the 1/4 cycle of a sine wave.  It is meant to rapidly load and unload a transformer. This question only referred to the front end of the circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Op-amp precision rectifiers are the likely turn-to solution. Here's [an example circuit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Op-Amp_Precision_Rectifier_%28Improved%29.svg): -

[image]

When the input is positive, the op-amp is prevented from creating an inverted (negative) output by D1 but, when the input is negative, the natural situation is for a positive output to be produced and, of course, D1 allows this. D2 prevents output saturation of the op-amp when the input is positive i.e. keeps it in the linear region.

The circuit produces a positive half wave rectified output.

If the diodes are reversed then you get a half-wave rectified output when the input is positive and 0 volts when the input is negative. You can then add another inverting stage after this so that you get the polarity you require.

So, two precision op-amp circuits are needed and both are fed from \$V_{IN}\$. If you need to have a decent square wave output, add comparators to both output channels.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tips. I eventually got a 4N25 opto to work with two outputs, one positive sine high and one negative sine high. The Duty cycle is not quite 50% but when voltage gets up close to 110v it's about 52% and 48%. That's the only area still needing some tweaks.

Here is the circuit (v 4) and the scope shots. The resistor feeding the Opto is a 2k.

Version 4 circuit
Positive Sine High
Negative Sine High